# How Position Numbering

Tags: java, android, xamarin, position, getview

How is position numbering data in **getview method**?

```
public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: 1st item is 0, 2nd item is 1 and so on

Comment: Maybe it'll be a sample to understand it better : [Click Button in ListView And Get Item Position](http://jmsliu.com/2444/click-button-in-listview-and-get-item-position.html)

Comment: @jb15613 :) I know that, my problem is all items numbering or only showed items??

Comment: Mr @BzH, Are U Iranian?

Comment: You need to ask a more concise question